# Sound: No output or input devices found

Tags: high-sierra, audio

2016 MBP 13-inch 4 Thunderbolt 3 ports running macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6

All of a sudden, my sound isn't working, and using the volume buttons show a mute icon with a stop sign underneath. In my sound preferences, it shows no output or input devices.

Running `system_profiler SPAudioDataType` in Terminal gives this output:

```
Audio:

Devices:
```

[image: Sound Preferences showing no output devices found message]

Comment: It appears your audio hardware has failed.  First thing would be to run [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.  If no errors, then try in Safe Mode (hold Shift while booting).

Comment: I shut down my Mac, then turned it on and held down the D key. A list of languages showed up, and I selected English and pressed enter. A progress bar came up and it said Checking your Mac... After it completed, it said that no issues were found. After restarting back into normal mode, it seems to have been resolved and everything is back to normal now. Thank you very much!

Comment: restart + D worked for me as well.

Comment: This also worked for me (restarting without holding D didn't work).

Comment: Restarting and doing the hardware test worked for me when a normal restart didn't as well.

Comment: Push (Shift) (control) (alt/option) (power) all at the same time starting with shift. It worked for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reboot the computer and hold D to run the Apple Hardware Test. In my case, it said no issues were found, but after rebooting, everything started working again. Based on the comments, many others have had the same experience.

Thanks to Allan for suggesting the hardware test.

Comment: I don't know how it can but this solved my problem too

Comment: Lo and behold! It worked! I guess the diagnostic tool will somehow magically correct whatever was messed up in NVRAM which prevents the driver from recognizing the sound chip.

Comment: Did all these resetting nvram, smc , D. Even after removing headphone it shows only headphone in output. 

Comment: Sadly a restart is not THE solution! Apple is doing nonsense! Customers are paying thousands of dollars to get a reliable device while they can't even fix this issue! I have to reboot my mac during a meeting because I can't hear any sound anymore. Or I have to plug in my headphones or connect to a Bluetooth device. This is not okay Apple!